# What's the best way to upgrade Go to 1.18 on Alma Linux?

Tags: upgrade, dnf, golang, alma-linux

I need to upgrade the version of Go on my Alma Linux 8 box from the installed version 1.16 to the latest 1.18.

There are several tutorials on how to install, but I haven’t found any for upgrade specifically, as there were for PHP.

The reason I ask is because Go is already installed, and I want to make sure I’d correctly upgrade if there’s a process already in place.

`dnf list golang` gives me:

```
Installed Packages
golang.x86_64                                                                         1.16.12-1.module_el8.5.0+2604+960c7771                                                                         @appstream
```

Or, do I re-install from scratch, [like this](https://nextgentips.com/2021/12/28/how-to-install-go-1-18-on-rocky-linux-almalinux/)?

Comment: Um, instructions on how to install (or upgrade) PHP will have nothing to do with Go.

Comment: Hm, not sure why you want to **upgrade** your system go. That would potentially require rebuilding all the tools that your system brings that depend on Go 1.16 (esp. thinks built with `-linkshared`). The saner variant would seem to me to have a separate go 1.18 installation that you only use to compile the software you need to be compiled with go 1.18.

Comment: It looks like Centos Stream 8 has a newer golang (1.17) in appstream, which is probably provided by a go dnf module. I’m sure once 8.6 drops, it’ll get built for AlmaLinux.

Comment: Thank you @jsbillings.  Please put that in an answer so I may mark it.

Comment: Another thing that you can do if you just want the latest version is to get the source code: https://github.com/golang/go/tags, compile it, and then add it to your environment.